# Django renaming field returns only int id not object

Tags: python, django, filter

I have the following Django model fields:

```
first_message = model.ForeignKey(FirstMessage)
second_message = model.ForeignKey(SecondMessage)
```

whereas only one of those will be filled in the DB, never both of them at the same time.

Now I have following filter condtion:

```
# state_model_field can be either 'first_message' or 'second_message'
field_filter = {f'{stats_model_field}__isnull': False}

objects = (MessageStats.objects
                       .filter(**field_filter)
                       .prefetch_related(stats_model_field)
                       .annotate(message=F(stats_model_field))
                       .values('message')
                       .order_by('message'))
```

The objects field should contain all `MessageStats` with the joined `FirstMessage` or `SecondMessage` table. In order not to have to distinguish between the fields in the future, I want to rename whichever field `state_model_field` is to the alias `message` (with the annotate).

However, the results are returned as a `dict`

```
{'message': 1}
```

but I want the full object of wither `FirstMessage` or `SecondMessage`!?

Answer (score 0):

To get message value from FK: `annotate(message=F(stats_model_field + '__message'))`

To get an object try to access original fieldname after `select_related`, e.g. `objects[1].first_message`

But after `.values('messages')` you will get only annotated `message` field values, that's all. No objects, just dicts containing a single key-value `{'message': 'asdf'}`.